# Get header/footer list for a theme

Tags: themes, templates

I Mauro from ACPT :)

I developed a new plugin for a complete solution for custom post types.

The plugin comes with a custom visual builder for single and archive templates.

It works fine, but there is still a big issue.

The editor allows the user to modify the main content of the page, the area between header and footer.

To better crarify, this is the code of the single template page:

```php
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying single custom post type
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/single-{custom-post-type-slug}.php.
 *
 * @since      1.0.0
 * @package    advanced-custom-post-type
 * @subpackage advanced-custom-post-type/templates
 * @author     Mauro Cassani <maurocassani1978@gmail.com>
 */

use ACPT\Core\Repository\TemplateRepository;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $post;

$template = TemplateRepository::get($post->post_type, 'single');

add_action('wp_head', function () use ($template) {
    do_action( 'acpt_custom_styles', $template );
}, 100);

get_header( $post->post_type );
do_action( 'acpt_before_main_content' );
do_action( 'acpt_single_content', $template );
do_action( 'acpt_after_main_content' );
get_footer( $post->post_type );
```

The dynamic part is between the functions `get_header( $post->post_type );` and `get_footer( $post->post_type );`.

This solution (taken from WooCommerce) works in many cases, but sometimes it's a total mess.

I would like to give to the user the ability to drag to the editor all available headers/footers for a particular theme.

How can I achieve this? Fetching the files of the theme is not sufficient, I guess (some theme have a custom header management system).

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance to all :)

M

Comment: are you asking how to get a list of `header-XXXXX.php` files from the theme as an array? Or how to modify your UI to select them? Or something else? I'm not sure why you added the `wp-blog-header.php` tag as it isn't related to this

Comment: Hi, maybe the tag wp-blog-header.php is wrong, sorry for that.

I want to allow the user to select a header from a list instead of hard-coding it.

I am not sure that looping header-xxx-php files is sufficient, because some themes have a sort of templating manager.

Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: for those themes that do their own thing you'd have to implement theme specific code and research how they work on a case by case basis, which may not be possible. For `get_header` you're limited to `header-xxxx.php` type files or `header.php`, likewise with `get_footer`. Note that none of this will work in block based themes, the site editor, or themes with mixed block templates